# InAppBrowser hidespinner iOS spinner still showing

Tags: cordova, phonegap, inappbrowser

I'm using my custom spinner during page loading and I'd like to totally disable native iOS spinner cause it's still showing when the page is not fully loaded.

So with InnAppBrowser, I'm using open() with "hidespinner=yes" option. Nevertheless, the native spinner still appears (on iOS only). Do you have any clue to force disabling it ?

```
var options = "location=no,enableViewportScale=yes,zoom=no,disallowoverscroll=yes,transitionstyle=fliphorizontal,toolbar=no,hidespinner=yes";
var view = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, target, options);
```